# Access Denied to zipfile created using python

Tags: python, windows, python-zipfile

I was able to create a zip file using the below code:

```
import os
import zipfile

user = input('Please enter your ID:')
date = input('Please enter the date:')

os.chdir('C:/Users/'+user+'/Desktop/Files/')
name = 'Position_'+date+'_Global'
newzip = zipfile.ZipFile(name+'.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) 
newzip.write(name+'.txt')
print(newzip.infolist())
newzip.close()
```

The code runs successfully, but I am facing access denied error while trying to open the zip file.

**Compressed (zipped) Folders Error:**

**Windows cannot open the folder.**

**Access to the Compressed (zipped) Folder
'C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/Files/Position__Global.zip' is denied.**

I am not sure what is causing the issue. Could you please check?

Comment: Works fine for me, what does the python script output?

Comment: This likely isn't the cause but I'll mention it just in case, It seems that if you are not an administrator on the computer (at least in Windows 7), you can create zip files but cannot open them up nor delete them (and a few other actions, I believe).

Comment: I don't believe above answer, you created files on your desktop and you cannot access them for not administrator ?

Comment: BOB is right. It was due to administrative privileges being set by default on my office PC. I tried the same code on my personal laptop & it works fine

Comment: This is going on my list of reasons why MS-Windows, is not suitable for real work.

Answer (score 0):

My office IT team debugged this:

The issue was due to restrictions on user privileges on my office PC. It occurs when you have user access but the python is being executed as Administrator. Then the file created by the administrator will not be available to be opened by common user.

Comment: So is it a `zip` thing as suggested by @BOB or is it because python is running as admin? (`python' is installed set-uid root, so anyone can run arbitrary code as admin)

Answer (score -1):

Most of time, it happened at some application open the file and not closed. Remember to close the opened file in your script, or try to close your application when failed before you close the opened file.

```py
import zipfile

newzip = zipfile.ZipFile('D:/test.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
newzip.write('D:/test.txt')
print(newzip.infolist())
# newzip.close()
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26458019)

Comment: Not critique or request clarification from an author. I do it and find the solution to close the file.

Comment: Automatically generated comment from review, sometimes it doesn't match the content. Anyway, the point is that unless you have a proper solution, it's still a comment/suggestion and that's most likely you got downvoted for by someone else i.e. posting a suggestion as an answer.

Comment: You needed to comment out a line to create this error. You might want to add, given the script provided in the question, how it could be that while the file is properly closed in the script, you think it's still open.

Comment: No, not so. Sometime, statements got error and execution stop, get this problem. For directly I comment the close statement. The same if I got some failure to break, maybe you still say I make some errors to make it true. If no problem, why get trouble there, right ?